# Why is my SOLIDWORKS background black?

Tags: solidworks

my solidworks background (where we do the modeling like drawing a line or a circle) and all the buttons (like close or minimize buttons) are black . they are there and I even can click on them and I even can do the drawing but I can't see them because the are completely black.
P.S. I had the same problem with photoshop before with the same laptop .

Comment: Can you add screenshots? What graphics card and driver do you have installed? Has this behaviour started recently, or has it always been this way since you installed SW? The fact you have had the problem with Photoshop points towards a hardware issue...

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to settings
2. Select colors tab
3. Reset colors to Defaults
   [image]

Hope this should help

Comment: This is a good answer, and may help someone else who is googling this problem - but the comment saying it's happened in Photoshop makes me think this isn't the actual problem that OP was having. He hasn't responded to my request for clarification, though - so it's clearly not that urgent...